# Jquery multidimensional array of DOM element children

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the DOM hierarchy of id's into a javascript array.  (I'm using jQuery UI sortable to rearrange DIVs and their toArray and serialize present a flat (non-hierarchical) result).

Code built on other SOF jfiddle solutions and such, here's my sandbox:

**UPDATED** http://jsfiddle.net/rfwkQ/2/

How would one go about iterating through the DOM children and recording their id's into a multidimensional array?

**EDIT:**

```
function getChildren(elem) {
var parent = [];
if ($(elem).children().length !== 0) {
    $(elem).children().each(function() {

        if ($(this).find('> div').children().size() !== 0) {
            var child = getChildren(this);
            parent.push(child);
        } else {
            parent.push(this.id);
        }
    });
    return parent;
}
}
```

I've assembled the above function to attempt to iterate the Divs and their children.  Returns the Div's in a multidimensional array.

**Further Question**
   This creates an empty string element in higher level nested divs.  How can I fix this in my logic, rather than creating a if not empty type check (which would be a good idea anyways, says me).

Sandbox 2.0: Link Updated Below

**Finally Solved** (Thanks to 'shoky' on #jquery on freenode irc)

http://jsfiddle.net/rfwkQ/8/

```
function getChildren(elem) {
var parent = [];

$(elem).children('div').each(function() {
    parent.push( 
        $(this).children('div').length ? getChildren(this) : this.id);
});

return parent;
}
```

Comment: It is usually not necessary to build your own copy of the DOM since you can iterate the DOM or query the DOM without making copies of the whole structure.  What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I should have been clearer, I only want the DOM id's I've generated of the sortable, the jsfiddle jquery ui sortable as an example.  (Ultimate goal is to do a $.ajax call to a DB)  I should also say, that Div's can be removed or added into the sortable.  What's the best way to check for non-null and index the id array for the children?

Comment: I added a plain javascript implementation to my answer which is probably significantly faster than your jQuery version (if that matters).

Answer (score 1):

You can walk the DOM using two properties of DOM nodes: `firstChild` and `nextSibling`.  Start with `document.body`, get the `firstChild` and go from there looking at each `firstChild` and `nextSibling` that is not null.

It's easiest, though not fastest to do it with recursion.

FYI, as I said in my comment, usually you do not want to build your own copy of the DOM because the DOM can be queried or traversed to serve pretty much any purpose without building a whole new copy of the structure that is instantly out-of-date as soon as a change is made.

Here's some plain javascript to solve this:

```
function getIdList(parent) {
    var list = [];
    var node = parent.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.tagName == "DIV") {
            list.push(getIdList(node));
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    // if no children, just return the id of the parent
    if (list.length == 0) {
        list = parent.id;
    }
    return(list);
}
```

And a working demo on your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TLVr7/ (scroll down to see a text version of the nested arrays).

Comment: Added plain javascript code example which is probably much more efficient than the jQuery version.

Comment: Firefox (at least mine, windows7/ff13) annoyingly gives lowercase results for `.tagName` so you can't get away without `.toLower/UpperCase()`

Comment: @Esailija - per the spec, if it's an XML doc, `.tagName` preserves case from the source doc, but it it's an HTML doc, `.tagName` is uppercase.  That's what I'm seeing.  The jsFiddle as is works for me in Firefox 13, Safari, Chrome and IE9.  Did you have a problem with the jsFiddle in FF13?

Comment: In chrome console: `document.createElement("div").tagName === "DIV"`
In firefox console: `document.createElement("div").tagName === "div"`. Though in the jsfiddle it gives uppercase in both chrome and firefox. Even in firefox console (ran on jsfiddle), maybe it's dependent on doctype or something?

Comment: @Esailija - as I said, it is dependent upon docType.  HTML is uppercase.  The console probably doesn't have a docType.

Comment: Yeah I noticed I used the console on `about:home` which doesn't have a doctype so it gives lowercase. Chrome gives uppercase regardless of the presence of doctype. This is all in html btw. Edit: Ok firefox gives `"DIV"` even without doctype now as well. So I guess the `about:home` is xml?